# linq paging not returning correct page if all sort column values are the same

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities, paging

With the following code:

```
repository.Invoices.OrderBy(i => i.Date).Skip(page * 10).Take(10)
```

If I have 100 invoices, and 50 are from the same date, then for the first 5 pages i get exactly the same resultset returned (which is records 1-10). In order to get around this I also have to sort on a unique key:

```
repository.Invoices.OrderBy(i => i.Date).ThenBy(i => i.Id).Skip(page * 10).Take(10)
```

Is there a more 'correct' way to ensure that paging works as expected? I'm using SQL server 2014 which converts the skip/take code to

```
OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Why don't you just order by the ID column instead?

Comment: Maybe because business rules of application may require to order data by date? And Id might not be auto-increment int but random number or guid (uniqueidentifier) or whatever instead.

Comment: Logically the sort key should be unique. Personally i'd throw a .ThenBy(i => i.Description) before the 'Id' sort.

Comment: @serhiyb If the ID is not auto increment but in random no. or GUID then it's useless to order by that column, instead, order by description is more logical.

Comment: Its not useful because initially data is ordered by date (app business logic requirement) and OP sorts it by Id after to make sure equal dates are sorted in the same order after repeating calls. Sorting by description is worser performance wise. Id usually has clustered index key + performance of comparing ints/guids is much more higher comparing to text/varchar/nvarchar comparison.

Comment: The Id is an autoincrementing primary key, and as serhiyb guessed it's an application requirement to be able to sort on any column shown in a table. So for the 100 invoices, the 50 records from the 30th december should show on the first 5 pages in some sane order, and then the other 50 records from January the next year should show on the latter 5 pages. I guess doing the secondary sort by id is the best solution here

Comment: Something similar happened to me. It looks like that entityFramework doesn't remember the order which was used for the previous page of results and shows some results on the first and second page. But when ordered by Id, everything is fine. That does look really weird to me, this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the most elegant solution but...

```
public class IndexedInvoice
{
    public int Index {get; set;}
    public Invoice Invoice {get; set;}
}
```

then in your code

```
int i = 0;
var selected = repository.Invoices.ToList().OrderBy(i => i.Date).Select(x => new IndexedInvoice(){Index = i++, Invoice = x});
```

Then you could wire the paging into the Index property.

Comment: You can't select a concrete class on a queryable in entity framework. Even if you actuated first, the point of the paging here is for performance reasons, so that not all records are retrieved from the db at once

Comment: Added tolist which i know you can do because i do it all the time. 


Though you make a great point about performance

Comment: could you do it in a stored proc with an order by date and a row_over()?